# Single checkbox value as Yes or No fetched in an email template

Tags: php, html

New to PHTML and HTML and wondering how can I get a single checkbox value under .phtml file fetched under a .html email template file as Yes and No?

For example, if user checks the checkbox then in email I want it like Free trial- Yes and if the user doesn't check the checkbox then it should come in email as Free Trial- No.

Codes and form SS are below,

[image: Form SS]

Form code is under quote.phtml file where checkbox code is written as per below,

```
<p class="free-trial-wp"><input type="checkbox" placeholder="I 'd like a free trial" name="all_sizes" value="All" checked ><span></span>&nbsp; I'd like a <strong>free trial</strong></p>
```

email template code is under quote.html as per below,

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<table>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Email: {{var email}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Organistaion: {{var organisation}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Contact Name: {{var contact}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Quote For: {{var productname}}</td></tr>  
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Contact Number: {{var telephone}}</td></tr>   
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Message: {{var comment}}</td></tr>            
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Free trial requested: {{var data.all_sizes}}</td></tr>
</table> 
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

I only need to receive email with Yes or No value depending on if check box is checked or not. So please let me know where I should make changes in my files, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you use Magento 1.9.x, it's right ?

If yes, you can use the `depend` condition or `if` condition :

```html
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<table>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Email: {{var email}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Organistaion: {{var organisation}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Contact Name: {{var contact}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Quote For: {{var productname}}</td></tr>  
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Contact Number: {{var telephone}}</td></tr>   
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Message: {{var comment}}</td></tr>            
    {{depend data.all_sizes}}<tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Free trial requested: Yes</td></tr>{{/depend}}
</table> 
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

```html
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<table>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Email: {{var email}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Organistaion: {{var organisation}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Contact Name: {{var contact}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Quote For: {{var productname}}</td></tr>  
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Contact Number: {{var telephone}}</td></tr>   
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Message: {{var comment}}</td></tr>            
    <tr class="subscribe-email-intro"><td>Free trial requested: {{if data.all_sizes}}Yes{{else}}No{{/if}}</td></tr>
</table> 
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: Hi Simon thanks for the response, I use Magneto 2.3, would the solution you posted still work for 2.3?

Comment: Neha, I don't use Magento :)
But I think, yes. See the documentation : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html
`depend` and `if` are still use

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'll check and get back.

Comment: Simon, it didn't work as expected as even after checkbox is checked, the email I am getting says No.

Free trial requested: No

Comment: Simon I tried the {if }condition as you showed but it's only showing No even the checkbox is checked. Is these any logic we are missing in the {if} condition?

Comment: Can anyone else help here please?